# Integrate GIF in Swift 3 iOS 8 application

Tags: ios, swift, gif

I want to integrate a GIF in my Swift 3 application. I found a lot of libraries for this but the problem is the compatibility: I use Swift 3 and the application is for iOS 8 or greater.  I can’t find a library using those requirements. I tried to open the GIF in photoshop, generate the PNG of each layer (more than 100 layer) then tried to do the animation by code (animation using an array of images) but the result is not what I was expecting: The animation doesn’t respect the size of the imageView that I had specified from the storyboard. I think that the source of the problem is that the generated PNG doesn’t has the same size.

Any help please?

Comment: what do you mean by 'integrate a GIF in my Swift 3 application'? do you want to just present it in UIImageView?

Comment: Yes the GIF will be as a loader that I can start and stop animation

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [this library](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif/). It's not written in swift, but you can add bridging header and use it as well.

EDITED:

sorry for long answer; you can download an example project, it works; 
there used this code:

```
self.variableDurationImageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:url];
```

so in swift it would be something like this:

```
myImageView.image = UIImage.animatedImage(withAnimatedGIF:url)
```

try it for yourself and feel free to comment here, if got any problems

EDITED:

you can also try [this](https://github.com/kiritmodi2702/GIF-Swift)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can is there methods to start and stop the animation? And what about the compatibility?

Comment: Please I added the UIImage+animatedGIF.h and the UIImage+animatedGIF.m to my app then I added #import"UIImage+animatedGIF.h" to my bridge but how can I use the `animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData` method? Have you please an example of use?